# Filtering a sum of cosines

Tags: filters, linear-systems, modulation, cosine

The block diagram below represents a linear modulation system operating at the frequency of $1000 Hz$, $f_C = 1000 Hz$, transmitting the message $m(t) = 2\cos(400πt)$

[image: Figure 1]

At point B, i got the signal: $$cos(1600 \pi t) + cos(2400 \pi t)$$

At point C, I got the following signal: $$\frac{1}{2} (\cos(380 π t) + \cos(420 π t) + \cos(3620 π t) + \cos(4420 π t))
$$

However, I am having difficulty acquiring $y(t)$. Would the filter $H(f)$ eliminate the entire signal from point C through?

Comment: In my head, I'm note even getting closely the same thing as you at (C); maybe I'm wrong though. How did you arrive at your term? Please edit your question and include your derivation!

Comment: In point B, i multiplied $m(t)cos2000\pi t$. In point C, i multiplied $x_{1}(t)cos(2020 \pi t)$.

Comment: Hint: it's easier if you don't take the 2 out of $2\pi t$; anyway, I don't see how you arrive at $1600\pi t$, could you also explain that in your question?

Comment: aaaaah I now see that $m(t) =\cos(2\pi 200t)$, OK, that can make more sense.

Comment: So, I recommend making your life easier: 1. set $a=2\pi t$.Lug that around and only insert it at the very end. Especially, do not multiply the 2 from $2\pi$ with the other numbers! Remember what the frequency of $\cos(2\pi f t)$ is!

Comment: 2. $x_2(t)=m(t) · (\cos(2\pi 1000 t) \cdot \cos(2\pi 1010 t))$, so calculate the product $(\cos(2\pi 1000 t) \cdot \cos(2\pi 1010 t))$ first (just because the numbers look much nicer to work with) .

Comment: Sorry, but I'm still having trouble determining system output. All cosine frequencies are above $90Hz$.

Comment: I'm interpreting that the filter only lets through a frequency between $-90$ and $90Hz$, as all frequencies are higher than $90Hz$, it seems to me that the filter attenuates the entire signal form point C.

Comment: If the modulation is simply `m*x` then it does look like everything gets attenuated. But if it's of the form `(1+m)*x` then you'll get something. Maybe it's `2+cos()` instead of `2*cos()`?

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen, it's really $2cos(400 \pi t)$. Thus, I believe that $y(t) = 0$

Answer (score 0):

Your diagnosis seems right. When I just precompute the product of the two oscillators in my head, that gives me frequency components at $\pm 10$ and at 2010, so mixing a tone with frequency 200 with that yields frequency components at

- 190,
- 210,
- -190,
- -210,
- 1810,
- 2210,
- -1810 and
- -2210,

But nothing in $[-90;90]$.

PS: it's better to keep the 2 with the $\pi$, as it is part of the factor between frequency and angular frequency.